# Hot to debug playwright-dotnet tests with Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit, playwright-sharp

I'm trying to run **Playwright** locally by using debugging from **xUnit** and **AspNetCore.TestHost** and even if when I call the API endpoints the calls are successfully the SPA page is not loaded.

Are there any changes that I should do more to `WebApplicationFactory` ?

So far I've tried this approach :

**CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs**

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
        {
            return new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    // Make UseStaticWebAssets work
                    var applicationPath = typeof(Startup).Assembly.Location;
                    var applicationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(applicationPath);
                    var name = Path.ChangeExtension(applicationPath, ".StaticWebAssets.xml");

                    var inMemoryConfiguration = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        [WebHostDefaults.StaticWebAssetsKey] = name,
                    };

                    config.AddInMemoryCollection(inMemoryConfiguration);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder => webHostBuilder
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name)
                    .UseStaticWebAssets()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>());
        }
    }
```

**PlaywrightFixture.cs**

```
public class PlaywrightFixture
    {
        public PlaywrightFixture()
        {
            this.Playwright = Microsoft.Playwright.Playwright.CreateAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            var options = new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
            };

            this.Browser = this.Playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private IPlaywright Playwright { get; set; }

        public IBrowser Browser { get; private set; }
    }
```

**UnitTest1.cs**

```
public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>, IClassFixture<PlaywrightFixture>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private readonly PlaywrightFixture _playwrightFixture;
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory _factory;

        public UnitTest1(CustomWebApplicationFactory factory, PlaywrightFixture playwrightFixture)
        {
            _client = factory?.CreateClient() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
            _factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));

            _playwrightFixture = playwrightFixture ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(playwrightFixture));
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Test1()
        {

            var apiCallSimulation = await _client.GetAsync(@"\WeatherForecast");
            var contentResult = await apiCallSimulation.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var page = await _playwrightFixture.Browser.NewPageAsync();
            var result = await page.GotoAsync($"https://localhost:5001");
        }
    }
```

The `apiCallSimulation` receives a 200 and the call is made to the controller but If I try to access the link I'm unable to do it.

Is there a way to achieve to run test locally ?? I know there is the solution to start manually the project and give the url, but I would like to do it as it goes with integration tests.

I have in mind one more idea to use Pragma marks and if is in Development to run `dotnet .dll`  but then I might have an issue with Azure DevOps with CI/CD

Comment: did you solve this with net 6?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the TestServer is really a 'server' listening on a port or just in memory access to server without the tcp/ip part. If so, you don't have how to make playrigth use the same specific http client made for the in-memory server, because the httpclient and TestServer are using fake objects instead of real network one to provide fast tests

Comment: Fair point, but then how we could possible test it locally / debug it locally without having a running version somewhere?

Comment: not sure if we could use the playwright hooks to get response from you fake httpclient instead of the  real browser request to the running server 

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/network#handle-requests

is like proxy requests to you httpClient, not sure of works